# Beginner calling methods form other classes to main method? "void not allowed here" error

Tags: java

Firstly, here is the code:

**Main**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

CalledClass call = new CalledClass();
System.out.println(call.methodCalled());

}

}
```

**Class trying to call**

```
public class CalledClass {

        public void methodCalled() {

         System.out.println("test");

        }

}
```

I know void means to return nothing but what do I change, do I change the methodCalled method to another data type? If so what data type and how would I get the same results of printing that line out? Thanks.

Comment: There is no method named testParsing() in CalledClass!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the name for this example. I still get the same error even when the name has been changed. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your method 'methodCalled' already has a print statement [i.e. System.out.println()] - it will get printed just by calling the method.

When you say `System.out.println(call.methodCalled());` it means

1. call method methodCalled()
2. print output of the method.

But, in your case the method methodCalled() is not returning anything [as its return type is void]

Update your main method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalledClass call = new CalledClass();
    call.methodCalled();
}
```